# iOS UITableViewCell imageView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I initialize a tableviewcell with a small image while the large image is downloading. when the large image is downloaded I notify the tableView cell imageView to update the image but nothing happens.

This is my table view cell creation method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"EventTableViewCellID";

    EventTableViewCell *cell = [self.eventsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Event *e = [_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.eventTitle setText:e.eventTitle];

    if (e.largeEventImage) {
        [cell.eventImageView setImage:[e largeEventImage]];
    } else {
        [cell.eventImageView setImage:[e thumbImage]];
    }

    cell.event = e;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSString *dateString = [_formatter stringFromDate:e.eventDate];
    [cell.eventDate setText:dateString];

    return cell;
}
```

This method (in the tableView cell) is called when a image is fetched and it is supposed to update the cell image view

```
- (void)imagesDownloaded {
    if (self.event.largeEventImage) {
        [self.eventImageView setImage:_event.largeEventImage];
    } else {
        [self.eventImageView setImage:_event.thumbImage];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you refreshing it? `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: Is the `imagesDownloaded` method called? Did you try setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: How do you "notify the cell" - via `NSNotification`?

Comment: I cannot see where you are calling this method.

Comment: after get notify refresh your tableView as @PortlandRunner said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use AFNetworking library for that.

there is a class AFNetworking + UIImageView

this is the method for load and display the image...

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
             placeholderImage:@"Your thumbImage"
                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                         yourImageView.image = image;
                      }
                     failure:nil];
```

hope this helps you to done your work.